# Razor View if sentence not working

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I have this razor code

```
    <td>@Model.ProcessedOn.Value.ToUniversalTime() UTC 
@(Model.ProcessedOn.Value != null ?  (Model.SendingOn.Value.AddTicks(-(Model.SendingOn.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)) - Model.AddedOn.Value.AddTicks(-(Model.AddedOn.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)))</td>
```

I need to check if `Model.ProcessedOn` is different than null.

If it's different I need to show the subtract between `Model.SendingOn` and `Model.AddedOn` which are DateTime values. This code:

```
.AddTicks(-(Model.SendingOn.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond))
```

Is just to delete the Milliseconds.

I have a problem with the `@`. I already tried different ways but this sentence is returning error, I'm sure I'm just having some sintax error.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `@if([condition]){}` instead of [ternary conditional operator ?:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) , because you expect result only need one judgment.

The `?:` syntax is

> condition ? first_expression : second_expression;

```
<td>
    @Model.ProcessedOn.Value.ToUniversalTime() UTC
    @if (Model.ProcessedOn.Value != null)
    {
        @(Model.SendingOn.Value.AddTicks(-(Model.SendingOn.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)) - Model.AddedOn.Value.AddTicks(-(Model.AddedOn.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)))
    }
</td>
```

**Note:**

I would write display calculation in the `Controller` instead of `View`, The `View` only response for display data, the data had provided by `Controller`.

Comment: This if is not working also. Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new error throwing

Comment: @pedrodotnet I edit my answer :), I forgot to add `@()`